# Difference between sizeof(struct tag *) and sizeof(struct tag)

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

```
struct student_simple
 {
    int rollno;
    char *name; 
};
```

difference between

```
struct student_simple *s2 = malloc(sizeof(struct student_simple *)); 

struct student_simple *s3 = malloc(sizeof(struct student_simple ));
```

I am able to use both s2 and s3 without any problem but when I check the size in gdb

```
gdb$ p sizeof(struct student_simple) gives 16 

gdb$ p sizeof(struct student_simple *) gives 8
```

Comment: You do realize we can see the edit history of every post right?

Comment: how do i delete this question?

Comment: You can't you can flag it to close and wait for someone to do it. Or gather (i think) 20000 reputation to be able to close it yourself ;-)

Comment: @PriteshAcharya In the meantime bring back the original question instead of what you have done at present.Just looks ugly on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between [...] and [...]?

An asterisk sign. And that if you try to use `s2` for storing a `student_simple` structure, you'll get undefined behavior.

> How can a malloc of size 8 bytes store the student_simple structure as in s2?

It can't. Why do you think it can?

Comment: @PriteshAcharya "It just did" doesn't imply anything. It may work now, it won't work tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(struct student_simple *)` gives size of a pointer to `student_simple`, but 
`sizeof(struct student_simple )` gives size of a structure variable of type `student_simple`.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behaviour is undefined. Anything could happen, including the appearance of correct behaviour. Use the `s3` form, it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(any_Structure_Pointer)` will give 8  or 4  which is compiler bases. But `sizeof(YOUR_Structure)` will give size of addition of all datatypes which you are declared inside structure.

If you have doubt, check with `sizeof(int*), sizeof(void*)...`. which will give 8 or 4..